# Why my kafka consumer sometimes not listening messages?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I use older kafka consumer 0.8V. 
**Steps**

- Starting listener
- Send 10 messages .Listener listens around 4 messages.
- Send single message. Listener not listening
- Again single message published. Listener is not listening.

Can anyone explain this behaviour?

**Consumer**

```java
public class KafkaMessageListenerThread implements Runnable {

    private KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream;

    private final KafkaMessageListener baseConsumer;

    public KafkaMessageListenerThread(KafkaMessageListener consumer, KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]> stream) {
        this.baseConsumer = consumer;
        this.stream = stream;
    }

    public void run() {

        ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> itr = stream.iterator();

        System.out.println("listens....");
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println("kafka record : " + itr.next());
            byte[] data = itr.next().message();
            baseConsumer.receiveData(data);

        }
    }

}
```

**BaseConsumer**

```java
public void start()  {
        try {

            Map<String, Integer> topicCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            topicCountMap.put(topic, CoreConstants.THREAD_SIZE);
            Map<String, List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>>> consumerMap = consumerConnector
                    .createMessageStreams(topicCountMap);

            List<KafkaStream<byte[], byte[]>> streams = consumerMap.get(topic);
            executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CoreConstants.THREAD_SIZE);

            for (final KafkaStream stream : streams) {
                executor.submit(new KafkaMessageListenerThread(this, stream));
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            System.out.println("eror in polling");
        }
    }
```

**consumer properties**

```
key.deserializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
value.deserializer=com.xx.RawFileSerializer
zookeeper.connect=zookeeper.xx\:2181
serializer.class=com.xx.RawFileEncoderDecoder
bootstrap.servers=kafka.xx\:9092
group.id=test
consumer.timeout.ms=-1
fetch.min.bytes=1
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your consumer code?

Comment: You'll need to change your topicCountMap with one entry for each partionId. Let me know if it works.   http://stackoverflow.com/a/31037621/2104970

Comment: @Vishnu667 i created the topic count map for the equal number of threads.       topicCountMap.put(topic, CoreConstants.THREAD_SIZE);,  executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(CoreConstants.THREAD_SIZE);

Comment: How many partitions do you have for the topic ?

Comment: @Vishnu667 Topic:RawFile PartitionCount:1 ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
 Topic: RawFile Partition: 0 Leader: 1014 Replicas: 1014 Isr: 1014

Comment: Since you have only one partition there is no use having more than one thread Since only one consumer thread can read from a single partition. just set your thread size to 1 and check It.

Comment: @Vishnu667 yes. That constant has been defined as =1. I suspect there is something else i need to do in my topic/partion/properties?

Comment: You can also check these 
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-Myconsumerseemstohavestopped,why?